# PHP transform old Array push syntax into new one

Tags: php, arrays, array-push

got some code like

```
foreach ($aArray as $oObject) {
      array_push($this->_aOtherArray,
             array(
                   'foo' => $oObject->foo->value,
                   'bar' => $oObject->bar->value
             )
      );
}
```

Where I fill an array with other arrays in the foreach.
Which works pretty fine.
Now I want the same with the "new" array syntaxe like

```
array_push($_aOtherArray, "'foo' => $oObject->foo->value", "'bar' => $oObject->bar->value");
```

or something similar.

Thank you very much!

Comment: What is the new array syntax? And 'what doesnt work'. Be descriptive. This question is unclear.

Comment: Please tell us what error you get

Comment: Is the new syntax `$this->_aOtherArray[] = ['someValue'];`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for this syntaxe ?

```
foreach ($aArray as $oObject) {
  $this->_aOtherArray[] = [
               'foo' => $oObject->foo->value,
               'bar' => $oObject->bar->value
  ];
}
```

Comment: Okay yes thank you very much. That one was what I expected. Sorry that was my first question, next time I will me more specific.

Comment: No problem, mark this topic as closed.